# Arcane Emacs Problems

Tags: linux, emacs, editor

I'm having some problems with my emacs setup. I'm still fairly novice, but these things seem to be  abit more arcane than the usual. I use

1. tmux 1.3-1
2. in bash 4.1.5(1)-release
3. on Linux, ubuntu 2.6.35-22-generic
4. in a vmware guest (VMWare Fusion, Version 5.0.1 (825449)).

And I'm finding that these commands simply are not taking in the emacs that I setup.

- <kbd>C-a</kbd> : doesn't take me to the beginning of the line ?
- <kbd>C-M-S-v</kbd> : navigates other window down ; how do you navigate other window up?
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> : this does NOT select a visual block (or rectangle, in emacs speak)

I'm also trying to configure these, but can't seem to get anywhere.

- reduce line highlight
- no hard wrapping (auto line breaks) when typing a long line

My **~/.emacs.d/init.el** is pretty straightforward.

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

Any insights are appreciated

Comment: Admirably detailed in all the version numbers except for that of Emacs itself, which you haven't mentioned. `C-u M-x emacs-version RET`. That said, your problems are almost certainly due to the terminal not sending Emacs the keys you want it to. I'm not familiar with tmux... is that also the terminal emulator, or do you use it in conjunction with a terminal? If the latter, you should also list that. Does the same problem occur without tmux being involved? Does the same problem happen in GUI Emacs (if you can run it)?

Comment: Haa, right you are. **tmux** is a terminal multiplexer, an alternative to **screen**. And that was indeed blocking the `C-a` command prefix. And the emacs version is **GNU Emacs 24.0.92.1**. I still can't solve the other 2 issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>C-a</kbd> : doesn't take me to the beginning of the line ?

You are likely running inside `screen` or another application that might take <kbd>C-a</kbd>. If <kbd>C-a</kbd> also fails to work in bash running in the same terminal session, that is your problem. If not, type <kbd>C-h c C-a</kbd> to see how Emacs interprets <kbd>C-a</kbd>. To resolve it, either bind `move-beginning-of-line` to a different key in Emacs, or rebind the command key of your terminal multiplexer to something other than <kbd>C-a</kbd>.

- <kbd>C-M-S-v</kbd> : navigates other window down ; how do you navigate other window up?

Normally <kbd>C-M-v</kbd> is bound to `scroll-other-window` and <kbd>C-M-S-v</kbd> to `scroll-other-window-down` (meanings of scroll "down" and "up" in Emacs command names are somewaht counterintuitive). Under a terminal it is impossible to distinguish between a control-key and a shifted control-key, so your <kbd>C-M-S-v</kbd> is likely invoking the same command as <kbd>C-M-v</kbd>, `scroll-other-window`. Again, this is easy to confirm using <kbd>C-h c</kbd>.

- <kbd>C-x r y</kbd> : this does NOT select a visual block (or rectangle, in emacs speak)

<kbd>C-x r y</kbd> [yanks the last killed rectangle into the buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html), it has nothing to do with the appearance of selection.

- no hard wrapping (auto line breaks) when typing a long line

To disable line wrapping, add `(setq-default truncate-lines t)` to your init file.

Comment: So it turns out that **tmux** was indeed blocking the `C-a` command prefix. But I still can't solve the other 2 issues. 1) For scrolling the other window, `C-h c` gives me `C-M-v runs the command scroll-other-window`. And hitting `S-C-M-v` gives me the same result. So you're correct. But how do I scroll the other window up? It's not `C-C-v` (tongue-in-cheek). 2) And finally, how do you select a rectangle? It's not any of these `C-x r {r,k,y,o,c,t}`. Thanks.

Comment: And I just solved the rectangular selection problem. It was the highlight that was throwing me off. In vim, highlights are rectangular as well.

Comment: @Nutritioustim To solve 2), simply bind `scroll-other-window-down` to a key binding that your terminal emulator *can* generate. For example, add `(global-set-key "\C-\M-r" 'scroll-other-window-down)` to your `.emacs`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your feedback  user4815162342. Now, I **can** `scroll-other-window-down`. What I need is to `scroll-other-window-UP`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The reverse of `scroll-other-window-down` is `scroll-other-window`, and you said in your first comment the latter was already bound to `C-M-v`. Note again Emacs's strange usage of "up" and "down" in the context of scrolling. (For example, the Page **Down** runs scroll-**up**-command in Emacs.)

Comment: So you're saying I need to bind `C-M-v` to `scroll-other-window-down`, **not** `scroll-other-window`? And I'd need to do that in elisp.

Comment: Yes, and I included code that does that (using `C-M-r` as an example) [in the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337181/arcane-emacs-problems/13339754#comment18215953_13339754).

Comment: Ahh, right you are. Sorry. `scroll-other-window-down` actually scrolls the other window up. Very unintuitive, as you say. Cheers :)

Comment: Nutritioustim: Even if it seems unintuitive, the `scroll-other-window-down` command does in fact scroll the window *down*, exactly as it says. Very much like a scroll (oddly enough), that's how you bring the text above into view.